# Why are the two divs not hidden in smaller devices using media queries

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this CSS :-

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .adsleft ,  .adsright { display:none !important; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px) {
  .adsleft ,  .adsright { display:none !important; }
}
.adsleft {
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 203px;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 114px;
  height: 1156px;
}
.adsright {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 203px;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 114px;
  height: 1156px;
}
```

The error is that the two divs `.adsleft` and `.adsright` are not hidden in mobile. Why is this happening?

Comment: There's probably more here than we can see. Try putting the media queries after the other code. The second one is redundant, as it's covered by the first.

Comment: It works fine in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/aj_r/77pn7vk1/. What is the screen width of your mobile device? Also, are you setting the display property anywhere else in css/javascript?

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: It is also possible you don't have the proper meta "viewport" tag in the head.

Comment: Once it works you should be able to remove the `!important`